# external hard drive can not be fornatted

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, formatting, hard-drive-failure

While I was formatting my external hard drive (this one: http://nl.transcend-info.com/Products/No-284), another program that was running caused a failure that aborted the formating. Since then, I have not been able to use the hard drive. 
When I attach the drive (via usb) to a computer, I get the message that it needs to be formatted before it can be used. When I then attempt to format it, the system refuses to do so and reports that the disk is "read only".

What can I do to make the drive useable? How can I still force format it? There is no hardware switch to write-protect the drive, so it has to be done  software-wise. How to (force) format a disk that is reported to be read only?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: Which operating system? How did you try to format (command line / UI)?

Comment: I have tried with Win10 x64, win7 x32, and on an Apple. Yes, I have tried from the command line as well: "format" and "diskpart".

Comment: you could try to boot a live gparted usb flash drive to see if gparted will be able to do it - see [here-gparted web site](http://gparted.org/). you could try also with another cable but I think that there could be something wrong with the controller if gparted will fail.

Comment: Since noone else is offering some advice here, I'll say that I think you should be fine after nullifying all blocks, either by means of `dd` which is somehow also available for Windows (although possibly only in package with `cygwin` or so) or by some windows specific tool. I don't consider this an answer but if you do some research in that direction you should be able to format afterwards, unless the device actually got really damaged on a lower level, which is not likely.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the other comment due to browser crash and cache effects. A bare-bone partitioning tool is definitely worth a try.

Comment: I'd recommend you to run the HDD manufacturer's diagnostic tool to check up on the health and SMART status of the external, @Peter. I'd also second the suggestion about [writing zeros to the entire drive](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10464/why-is-writing-zeros-or-random-data-over-a-hard-drive-multiple-times-better-th) using a formatting utility. However, keep in mind that this would erase all the files on it to the point of no return. Once this is done, you should be able to initialize it and then partition & format it from Disk Management. Good luck!